# XMPP: Как получить входящие сообщение?

Tags: python, xmpp

Как получить входящие сообщение и вывести их на консоль, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для библиотеки xmpppy зарегистрировать обработчик сообщений:

```
def msgHandler(cl, msg):
    print msg.getBody()
Client.RegisterHandler("message", msgHandler) # Client - объект xmpp.Client
```